# How to update custom sequelize timestamp field?

Tags: mysql, sql, model, sequelize.js

The timestamp field in sequelize model is defined like this (note: it has to be called last_scraped):

```
last_scraped: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE, 
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW, 
},
```

MySQL query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `businesses` (`site`,`name`,`business_type`,`address`,`price`,`url`,`last_scraped`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name`=VALUES(`name`), `price`=VALUES(`price`), `url`=VALUES(`url`), `site`=VALUES(`site`), `address`=VALUES(`address`);
```

On first insert, last_scraped field is populated, but the problem is that it is not changing on update.

How can I fix this? Is there any way to do it without using `createdAt` and `updatedAt?`

Comment: Try to use hooks to set last_scraped balue

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
last_scraped: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE, 
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
},
```